# How to use regs to modify wires?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I am kind of new to Verilog and was wondering how I can modify wires. I know that you cannot modify wires inside always blocks.

I've seen something like this where you can declare some regs and assign the wire to those regs (which you can then modify the reg to modify the wire?)

```
module something
#(parameter D_W = 8)
(
    input  wire clk,
    input  wire rst,

    output wire valid,
    output wire [D_W-1:0] data,
);

reg valid_rg = 0;
reg [D_W-1:0] data_rg = 0;
    
assign valid = valid_rg;
assign data  = data_rg;
```

I was wondering how to do something like that for a wire like:

```
wire    [7:0] wire_a  [7:0];
```

Initially my guess would be to have something like this

```
reg [7:0] wire_a_rg [7:0];
assign wire_a[7:0] = wire_a_rg[7:0];
```

But I have a feeling it might be wrong. How could I approach this?

Comment: The part of code you showed is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to use wires in SystemVerilog unless you need to model bi-directional buses, or any kind of circuitry with multiple drivers. You can write

```
module something
#(parameter D_W = 8)
(
    input  logic clk,
    input  logic rst,

    output logic valid,
    output logic [D_W-1:0] data,
);
```

And then you can make procedural assigmemnts to `valid`/`data` in an `always` block, or a continuous `assign` statement (but not both).

BTW, SystemVerilog prefers the use of `logic` keyword over synonym `reg`.

You should read my post about [the difference between nets and variables](https://blogs.sw.siemens.com/verificationhorizons/2013/05/03/wire-vs-reg/).